# Unable to create an option menu with items in left side, with an icon for each item

Tags: android

This is my .xml file. How do I set icons for them?

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item

    android:drawable="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/Home"
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/homep"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/home"/>
<item
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/examp"
    android:id="@+id/Exam_not"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/exam"/>
<item   
    android:icon="@drawable/newsp"
    android:id="@+id/L_news"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:title="@string/L_news"/>
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/galleryp"
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:title="@string/gallery"/>
```

How to set icons for them and create the menu on left side of device?

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: any one plz help me ???

Answer (score 0):

What you're showing appears to be a `NavigationDrawer` with either a number `LinearLayout` based rows, or backed by a `ListView`.

Refer to this tutorial from Google for more info: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html